# Serializing HTML form array to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a form containing a list of text fields

```
<input type="text" name="list[]" value="">
<input type="text" name="list[]" value="">
```

I'm running some custom jQuery to validate the input and do a few other things, before displaying a JSON chunk to the user. What I want to achieve is these elements should become a standard javascript array a la:

```
{"list":["something","something else"]}
```

Is there a simple call I can make on the specific element to pull it in as an array, something like this?

```
var jsonVars = {};
jsonVars['list'] = $("input[name=list]").getArray();
```

Comment: If you had an actual form you could do `$(form).serializeArray()`

Comment: @adeneo I do have a form, but I don't want to grab the whole form contents. I'd have to iterate over the whole map to find the one target I'm looking for that way.

Comment: I believe you could do `$('[input[name^=list]').serializeArray()` but the format isn't what your plugin wants. You would need to run that `serializeArray()` through another loopie loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the structure you have and assuming you want to get the values you could do:

```
var jsonVars = {};
jsonVars['list'] = $('input[name="list[]"]').map(function(){return this.value;}).get();
```

You can use [`$('input[name="list[]"]').serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) but will return in a different format as array of objects (with name and value).

Answer (score 0):

There's jQuery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function. [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery) is similar to yours and might give you some more advanced insight.